# как поменять ссылку но необходимо ее найти через id and tag (a)

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо заменить ссылку "sates0.html" на "index.html" но сначала найти ее нужно через id and tag (a).

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("foto").querySelector("a").setAttribute("href", "something2.html");
```

```html
<div id="foto">
<a href="something.html">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чем Вам первый ответ не подошел? Вот немного короче вариант и с ссылками что у Вас.

```js
document.querySelector('#foto a').href = 'index.html'
```

```html
<div id="foto">
  <a href="sates0.html">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: все работает лучший ты)))